# Why my server is loading these PHP variables?

Tags: php, linux, libraries

I'm migrating my server to a new dedicated, and after the migration my main website shows 500 Internal Error message, on error_log I see

```
[28-Feb-2014 22:29:14 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/suhosin.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/suhosin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[28-Feb-2014 22:29:14 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdo.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[28-Feb-2014 22:29:14 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdo_sqlite.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdo_sqlite.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[28-Feb-2014 22:29:14 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/sqlite.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/sqlite.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[28-Feb-2014 22:29:14 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/phar.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/phar.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[28-Feb-2014 22:29:14 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdo_mysql.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdo_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[28-Feb-2014 22:29:14 America/New_York] PHP Fatal error:  Directive 'allow_call_time_pass_reference' is no longer available in PHP in Unknown on line 0
```

I don't know why it is loading this many libraries, any way I can find out?

Should I just google them all and install them?

Comment: Umm...it's *not* loading that many libraries.  That's part of the problem.  :)  Each of those warning messages is about a failure to load a PHP extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your `php.ini` file; it refers to each of these libraries, or it wouldn't be trying to load them.

Comment: I have it open here in SSH, allow_call_time_pass_reference isn't even there

Comment: [allow_call_time_pass_reference was removed as of PHP 5.4](http://us3.php.net/ini.core). You should not be using it. You will get this error if you call functions and reference variables by reference. For example, `foo(&$myvar)`.  See [the manual](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.allow-call-time-pass-reference).

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that that specific website had a php.ini, wich had this variable. I couldn't find it earlier because I was looking on  /usr/local/lib/php.ini

Comment: Only thing now is that the latin characters got messed up somehow �

Comment: Re the latin characters: That, I have no idea about. I suggest you post a separate question and say how they got "messed up" -- it's going to be a different problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22109966/latin-character-showing-as-after-server-migration Thanks